# Solve the second degree differential equation $(1- y^2+ \frac{y^4}{x^2})p^2-\frac{2yp}{x}+\frac{y^2}{x^2}=0$

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, differential

Solve the second degree differential equation.

> $(1- y^2+ \frac{y^4}{x^2})p^2-\frac{2yp}{x}+\frac{y^2}{x^2}=0$ where $p=dy/dx$

I tried to solve as follows but got stuck. Please help. Other “good” ways to solve this equation are also welcome.

[image]

Comment: Where did that come from?

Comment: @user10354138: It was asked in one of my exams

Comment: That's not a second order differential equation, there is no $y"$ term, just a $(y')^2$ term.

Comment: I suspect substituting $u = y/x$ or $u = y^2/x$ would prove fruitful.  It's such an ugly mess, to be an exam question it must have a cute trick.

Comment: @RobertTheTutor: Fixed the mistake. I tried trying these substitutions but it gets messy. Second substitution seems better but still it gets ugly.

Comment: $y =a \sqrt{x}$ is so close to a solution I keep being convinced I've made algebraic errors.

Comment: @RobertTheTutor: I’m kinda convinced there is no neat solution for this problem.

Answer (score 1):

**Far from a solution, a small advance that may inspire you:**

Let us consider the half quadrant $x>y>0$ for which you have:

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\dfrac{y}{x-y\sqrt{x^2-y^2}}\tag{*}$$

Convert this differential equation into the equivalent differential system:

$$\begin{cases}\frac{dy}{dt}&=&-y& \ \ Eq. 1\\ \frac{dx}{dt}&=&-x+y\sqrt{x^2-y^2}& \ \ Eq. 2 \end{cases}$$

Eq. 1 gives $y=ae^{-t}$. Plugging this expression in Eq. 2, one gets:

$$\frac{dx(t)}{dt}=-x+ae^{-t}\sqrt{x^2-a^2e^{-2t}}$$

which has $x(t)=ae^{-t}$ as a particular solution.

Having $y=x$ as a solution is confirmed by the vector field associated with initial equation (*).

[image]